# Importing feature class from ArcGIS to SQL Server using database connection gives ERROR 000210

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, sql-server, error-000210

I am trying to import one point feature table "**Point**" to the SQL Server using the import option by right-clicking on the database connection folder under catalog. The new file name for the SQL database is **"Point_1"** I am getting an error msg and am unable to import the file to the SQL Server under the desired database (BRISK_AIS). I can see that a table in the SQL database but it is empty.
SQL database connection is working fine. I am able to drag table files from SQL Server database i.e. BRISK_AIS to ArcGIS window without any problem.

Any idea of this problem and a possible solution?

See figure below for illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When trying to import data into a feature dataset inside an enterprise geodatabase the copier must be the user that owns the feature dataset.

Here, In SQL Server, if the user is granted the Server Role `sysadmin` then that user will be recognized as the DBO. When the user creates data in the database it will be `<database_name>.DBO.<feature_class_name>`.

**A possible solution to the issue.**:

1. Make sure that the user trying to add data into a feature dataset is the owner of the feature dataset
2. If the user is the owner of the feature dataset, make sure the user hasn't been granted a sysadmin role (only in SQL Server)
3. In SQL Server Management Studio, navigate to the Security folder of the instance
   Open Logins
4. Right-click the Login>Properties
5. Under Server Roles, make sure the user doesn't have a sysadmin role
6. If the sysadmin role is given, try revoking the role and adding the data into the feature dataset again

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Regarding feature class "Point", I have made this file in ArcGIS and owns this and located in my local folder.
Regarding SQL server, I have checked in the sysadmin that I am not registered with a sysadmin role. In the figure it is shown that a new table is formed with <database_name>.DBO.<feature_class_name> i.e. BRISK_AIS.DBO.Points1 but it is emply.
Is there anything else I should check?